# Magento 2 share wish list email "View all Wish List items" link showing blank page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4, wishlist, share-wishlist

When I share my Wishlist in Magento 2, I am getting all the wish listed items to the given mail id and at the end of wish list items there is a link called "View all Wish List items". When I click on that link it is taking so much time and finally showing blank white page. This is the link address 
**<base_url>/wishlist/shared/index/code/ahQQK65iERuxpRCBzOHasb2Wsh5oUaEX/**.
 Is there any configuration needs to change for showing all these wishlist items when I click on it or is it an error ? Can you please share your solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: While open this URL, can you check console or error log?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find any console message or log message neither system.log not debug.log

Comment: Check the website mode, if that is not Developer mode then set that and check.